# How to Make a Javascript Popup Box on First Site Visit?

Tags: javascript, popup

I've attempted to search for this on Google, but I have no clue what it's actually called. It's basically a box that fades onto the screen on your first visit to the site (using cookies), and has an X in the top right corner that allows users to close it. Can anyone tell me what this is actually called, or show me how to make this? Thanks.

Comment: The dialog itself is usually called a *lightbox*.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the  existance of the cookie and set a cookie if it is not already there using jquery.

```
  if( $.cookie("visited")!='visited'){
       $.cookie("visited", "visited"); 
       $('#dialogDivId').dialog();
  }
```

And if the

```
<div id="dialogDivId">

It's your first visit...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript you need some functions to get and set the cookie.

Getting the Cookie information

`function getCookie(c_name)
{
var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++)
{
  x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
  y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
  x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
  if (x==c_name)
    {
    return unescape(y);
    }
  }
}`

Setting the Cookie information

`function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;
}`

Now check the cookie and display the popup box

`function checkCookie()
{
var popup=getCookie("popup");
  if (popup==null && popup=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("popupDivID").style.display="block";
  }`

HTML part

`<div id="popupDivID" style="display:none;position:absolute;top:20%;left:15%;background-color:#fff;width:500px;height:300px;">POPUP Content and Close Icon</div>`

You have to call the checkCookie() function on body onload. If you need jQuery solution please follow @Jayantha's solution.